# How to properly validate a form that resides on a file called via AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-validate

I'm having a problem validating a field in a form with a Submit button when the form is sitting on a php file that uses AJAX to pull in up on the current main page.

Here's a fiddle of the validation code and the simple form not using AJAX: 
http://jsfiddle.net/mwrfW/

That simple example works fine.
Now if I leave the JS in index.php but put the form on ajax_form.php I get a problem:

On index.php:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

$("#contactform").validate({
    rules: {
         name: {
             required: true,
             minlength: 3
         },
     },
     submitHandler: function () {
         alert('valid form submission');
         return false;
     }
    });
});
</script>
```

On ajax_form.php (where I echo out the html):

```
echo '<form id="contactform">
    A:<input id="name" type="text" name="name" />
    <br/>
    <input id="btn" type="submit" />
</form>';
```

So with that two file setup, validation isn't triggering.

Interestingly, if I bring the Submit button over to index.php and ditch the submitHandler it works as long as I add a little extra code to make the submit button work outside of the form: for example: on index.php:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#contactform").validate({    
         name: {
             required: true,
             minlength: 3
         },
    })

    $('#btn').click(function() {
        $("#contactform").valid();
    });
});
<input id="btn" type="submit" />
```

On ajax_form.php (where I echo out just the field's html):

```
   echo '<form id="contactform">
        <input id="name" type="text" name="name" />
    </form>';
```

So here's the overall question:

**What is the proper way to have the validation js on the index page, while the form/field/submitbutton all reside on the ajax_form.php?**

I'm not sure if I'm using the submitHandler correctly or not with this setup.

Just in case it's needed, here's the AJAX code that's calling ajax_form.php (fyi, the form always pulls up fine with this, so I don't think there's a problem with this part of the code):

```
//Edit Case
function editCase(str) {
  if (str=="") {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
    return;
  } 
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else { // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
          document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
          }
      }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax_form.php?q="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
$(document).ready(function(){

            $('.overlay').show();
            $('.button').show();

    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form element must be loaded in the DOM before the jQuery validate function can be attached to it. So I expect I'd either move the form to the index.php file and hide it until needed, or move the jQuery validation code to the editCase function, or put the jQ validation code in a function and attach that function to the form in the editCase function.

Here's an example of the last option:

```
function contactform_validation() {
    $("#contactform").validate({
        rules: {
             name: {
                 required: true,
                 minlength: 3
             },
         },
         submitHandler: function () {
             alert('valid form submission');
             form.submit();
         },
         invalidHandler: function () {
             alert('INvalid form submission');
             return false;
         }
        });
}

function editCase(str) {
    if (str=="") {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
        return;
    } 
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else { // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;

            contactform_validation(); // <--- THIS IS NEW

        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax_form.php?q="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.overlay').show();
        $('.button').show();
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi I understand what you mean: followup question...when I put javascript in the ajax_form.php file, it doesn't process. For example, if I put a simple <script>alert("working");</script> it doesn't work. I even tried echoing the JS alert out through the php. Is it supposed to work normally?

Comment: Oops, I messed that up. I said put the validation code in the ajax_form.php file. Rather, put the validation code in the editCase function. I edited the response above.

Comment: Got it to work by running my updateCase() function (comes after my editCase process..when saving the form on editcase.php) in the contactform_validation(); So the Save button's onclick calls contactform_validation();, and then if it's valid, updateCases() runs.

Answer (score 1):

You are using JQuery, so you can use `load()` function like this:

```
$('#txtHint').load("ajax_form.php?q="+str , null, function (){
   //and here in your callback function, you can attach all behaviors to your form, for example:
   $("#contactform").validate({    
        name: {
           required: true,
           minlength: 3
        },
   })

   $('#btn').click(function() {
       $("#contactform").valid();
   });
});
```

Comment: Hi Would I just add that into my editCase function? Would it replace my xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax_form.php?q="+str,true); or any of my other code?

Comment: Hi @Chain, yes, you can replace your ajax code from `if (window.XMLHttpRequest)`... to `xmlhttp.send();`